# SQL Foreign key issue with 2 parent tables

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have have 2 tables `User` and `Group`. 
I have a table `Attributes` *shared* by user and group with columns:

- `attributeName`.
- `AttributeValue`.
- `ObjectID`.

`ObjectID` points to either the primary key of user or the primary key of Group.
I have added a foreign constraint with `Cascade on Delete` in order to delete automatically the attributes when user or a group is deleted.

The problem now is when I insert an attribute for the user, I have a foreign key constraint because the group does not exist.

How should I proceed?

Comment: I think you should consider two attribute tables instead. One for User and one for Group.

Comment: or replace the foreign keys and constraint with triggers on the parent table to catch the delete?

Comment: I would not. The main purpose of the FK is not the cascade delete. It is there to make sure that you don't add attributes for Users/Groups that does not exist. Having the same field in Attributes for both UserId and GroupId is a bad idea. Instead of two tables you could have two columns in Attributes but as I said, I would go for two tables.

Comment: Yes, Climbage belows tends to the same answer. What bothers me is that I duplicate identical tables. In fact, I have 4 parent objects: user/group/contact/role. I will have to create 4 identical table to store the attributes.

Comment: And I have also a "link" table that links a source object (user or group) with a target object (user or group). The design of this table is fairly simple. It's generical IDROW | SourceID | TargetID. When I delete a user or a group (source or target), I want this link to be automatically deleted. As for the above sample, this "link" table is "shared" by users/groups/contacts... If I follow you I will have to create dozen of identical tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have basically 3 options:

1. Keep your current design, but replace  `Attribute.ObjectID` with `UserID` and `GroupID`, attach a separate FK to each of them (one towards `Group` and the other towards `User`) and allow either to be NULL. You'd also want a CHECK constraint to ensure **not both** of them are NULL.

   [image]
2. Split `Attribute` table to `UserAttribute` and `GroupAttribute`, thus separating each foreign key into its own table.

   [image]
3. Use inheritance, like this:

   [image]

The solution (1) is highly dependent on how your DBMS handles UNIQUE on NULLs and both (1) and (2) allow the same `AttributeName` to be used for two different attributes, one for user an the other for group.

Comment: Can you explain option 3 ? I don't understand how you related both group and user to object, is it 2 childs for 1 parent ?

Comment: @Suleman No. A user is represented by one row in `Object` and one row in `User`. Conversely, a group is represented by one row in `Object` and one row in `Group`.

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered you can not have one column as foreign key to two different tables. You can't add a attribute for a user when it does not exist a group with the same id. And you can of course not know if the attribute is for a user or a group.

From comments you also mentioned a m:m relation between user and group so I would suggest the following.

```
create table [User]
(
  UserID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(50) not null
)

go

create table [Group]
(
  GroupID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(50) not null
)

go

create table UserGroup
(
  UserID int not null references [User](UserID),
  GroupID int not null references [Group](GroupID),
  primary key (UserID, GroupID)
)

go

create table UserAttribute
(
  UserAttributeID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(50) not null,
  Value varchar(50) not null,
  UserID int not null references [User](UserID) on delete cascade
)

go

create table GroupAttribute
(
  GroupAttributeID int identity primary key,
  Name varchar(50) not null,
  Value varchar(50) not null,
  GroupID int not null references [Group](GroupID) on delete cascade
)
```

Note: The use of an attribute table should be for attributes you don't know before hand. All the stuff you know will be attributes should be fields in the actual table instead. Reserve the use of the attributes for customer defined attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should allow `NULL` values for this foreign key field `ObjectId`, so that you can insert any row with `ObjectId` = null that not referencing any user or group.

For a better design you should remove this `ObjectId` column, add a new column `AttributeId` to the two tables `User` and `Group`.